# My node.js server is running in intelliJ but localhost just serves a blank page

Tags: html, css, node.js, intellij-idea, mean-stack

I'm using the [mean](http://mean.io/) stack and intelliJ.  Whenever I run my node.js server I see this output in the intelliJ console:

```
path/bin/node --debug-brk=32865 server.js
debugger listening on port 32865
Express app started on port 3000
```

Then I browse to `localhost:3000/#!/test` I just get a blank page.  But it shows that I hit it in my intelliJ console.  Also if I just go to `localhost:3000/test` it shows the correct json for the page.  So its almost like its not aware of my html and css somehow?

How can I load my html and css correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to go into my root directory and run `npm install`.